# Give style following If condition in EJS

Tags: javascript, css, ejs

```
<% docs.forEach( function ( doc ){ %>

<div class="item">
    <% if (doc.Active) { %>
    <style> .item { background-color:red }</style>
    <% } %>
</div>

<% }); %>
```

Imagine 3 docs,

```
doc1 (Active == true)
doc2 (Active == true)
doc3 (Active == false)
```

I want to give style to `Active == true` only. I coded like above, but the result is every `div` was given style. so finally all has red background, this is not what I expected.

How can I give style conditionally in **EJS**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to conditionally set a class like `.active` and have that with your CSS styles (such as the red background-color). Like this:

```
<% docs.forEach(function (doc) { %>    
  <div class="item <%= doc.Active ? 'active' : '' %>"></div>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
<style> .item { background-color:red; } </style>
```

and to only set that to just one of the items, use:

```
<style>
   .active { background-color:red; } 
</style>

<% docs.forEach( function ( doc ){ %>

<% if (doc.Active) { %>
   <div class="item acitve">
<% } else { %>
   <div class="item">
<% } %>

   ...

  </div>

<% }); %>
```